# Zend_Router stop translating plus character into space

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

I have an API call that passes 10+ parameters, in no certain order.

```
http://domain.com/signup/format/json/email/bla/name/bla...
```

For our routes, we are using a config file fed in via

```
$frontController->getRouter()->addConfig($zend_config_object, 'routes');
```

The route for this action looks like this:

```
routes.signup.route = "/signup/*"
routes.signup.defaults.module = default
routes.signup.defaults.controller = index
routes.signup.defaults.action = signup
```

The * allows for the default param/value routing.  There is a param (email) that I am attempting to pass a value with a plus character (%2B), but it is being converted to a space.  Space is a valid email character, so I need a way to pass the space through routing in my RESTful URLs

I've read that this is default behavior.  Is there a way to override this behavior without requiring that params be passed in a particular order?

Answer (score 0):

plus is a reserved character to separate words use setWordDelimiter() in Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Abstract

also a good reference 
http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Comment: Thanks for the input!  When I use setWordDelimiter(array('.')) the issue still exists.  When I use getWordDelimiter(), only the period (.) and hyphen (-) are returned.  My app is running ZF 1.11.5